# Survivability of Definitions from One Letter to the Next

Tags: administrative-law

If I have defined a set of terms in a letter to a person at a state agency, and then I send a second letter to the same person to follow up on a related, but more specific matter which requires use of some of the same terms from the first letter, can I use terms in the second letter which I defined in the first?

Comment: Sure.  Include a sentence along the lines of "terms that were defined in my previous letter will have the same meaning in this letter unless otherwise noted."  Or, just avoid the question by copying and pasting the definitions from the other letter, which is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@phoog has it partially right.

Further online research has indicated that the phrase

```
"...and are incorporated herein by reference"
```

should be appended to the end of his suggested statement above.